# Merge with nonexisting id

Tags: hibernate, jpa

As you all know, EntityManager.merge() was introduced to merge changes made to a detached entity into an attached one. This suggests a pattern "fetch an entity, return its shallow copy to some client, let the client make some changes and send us updated instance, then merge updated instance back into persistence context", right?

But what if instance was deleted by third party while that client was playing with its detached copy? When we try to merge it back, one would expect to behave similar to SQL update: throw some exception of the sort "entity does not exist". One would be disappointed: JPA (at least in Hibernate implementation) will simply ignore the supplied ID in that case, and will create a new entity instead of updating the existing one.

How do I deal with that? I surely don't want to create new entity when the client just tried to updated a deleted one.

I suppose I can find the entity by id before doing merge (throw if not found), and rely on "repeatable read" to prevent entity removal (if any) from becoming visible to current transaction, ensuring merge() to update existing entity. That's a bit ugly however, especially given how merge() can cascade to nested entities and I'll have to find() those as well. I also tried to introduce @version hoping it will help and JPA will detect it's not right to create new entity if I am supplying a non-null base version, but that seemed to be ignored as well.

P.S. It just occured to me that I can allow JPA to create a new entity then check its ID against the one provided by the client. If, say, a sequence is being used to produce IDs, new ID will differ from the old one, and in this case I can throw exception and roll back the transaction. But that's still additional check, so this solution is no better than using find().

Comment: "I suppose I can find the entity by id before doing merge" - on second thought, that's probably the way to go in JPA, to use merge while having a current state of entity in EntityManager. Just like copying property values one-by-one - first fetch an object then modify it. Not sure however, have no time to dig JPA spec, and Javadoc is vague on that.

Answer (score 3):

You can check after doing the merge if the key is the same. 
If it is the same, it means that the merged object is the same, if not, it means that the detached entity has been deleted.

```
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    EntityClass mergedEntity = em.merge( detachedEntity );
    if( mergedEntity.getId() != detachedEntity.getId() ){
        System.out.println("Entity has been deleted !!!  Do rollback.");
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }else{
        System.out.println("Entity has been merged !!! Do commit ");
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

If you enable SQL tracing, you will see that while performing the merge opertion:
 `mergedEntity = em.merge( detachedEntity );`, Hibernate under the hood is doing:

- `SELECT ... FROM Entity WHERE id = id_of_detached_entity`
- if the above query finds a row, then Hibernate assingns the same Id to the merged entity object
- if the above query returns nothing, Hibernate fetches next Id value from the sequence and assings this value to the merged entity object, so the merged object has different Id that old, detached object.

Comment: Yes, I thought so (see my P.S.). But I hope someone has a cleaner solution, because this one looks, well, unnatural to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem a few days ago, and my thoughts about it were the same as yours. But, after reading carefully the simple message we get with OptimisticLockException: "Row was updated or deleted by another transaction" I recognized that probably we missed something important from the locking point of view:

- every locking type requires active transaction underneath, any lock acquired through transaction needs to be removed before the transaction is closed, so even we use the version for optimistic locking, outside transaction it means nothing,
- to get OptimisticLockException we need to have an entity that is already attached to the transaction context, in the time of merging detached entity we do not have such yet,

Summing up, using versioning outside transactions is not prohibited but when injected into a new transaction can produce unexpected results.

My solution with JPA is as follows:

```
@Transactional
public Account update(Account account) {
    if (accountJpaRepository.findById(account.getId()).isPresent()) {
        return accountJpaRepository.save(account);
    } else {
        throw new UpdatedEntityNotFoundException("Updated Account not found");
    }
}
```

- @Transactional - opening transaction context
- accountJpaRepository.findById(account.getId()).isPresent() - checking by id if provided entity Id exists in database, what more, if exists we take its copy into transaction context
- accountJpaRepository.save - saving detached entity by merging it with an entity that we have in the context already, not from the database

In this solution, we still using optimistic locking, so if something will happen (update, delete) to our entity in the database between calls find and save, then save will throw OptimisticLockException.

Ok, then what about cascade? I found somethig like this:

```
@OptimisticLock(excluded = false)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "transaction", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<TransactionCategory> transactionCategories;
```

`@OptimisticLock(excluded = false)` - it makes that any changes, made to the list or their items, will increment the version of the nesting entity even there are no direct changes to it. As you can see in the example there is CascadeType.ALL so relation is fully managed by nesting entity, but there are few more cascade types that I did not analyze, for each of them the solution needs to be a rethink.

Comment: In my question I mentioned "I suppose I can find the entity by id before doing merge (throw if not found)" and that's exactly what you do here. It just didn't seem right to me, especially because in SQL "update" can both check for existence and update an item, and because that's atomic whereas our solution is not (say, we did find it but right then some outside transaction deleted it) - though admittedly repeatable reads should help with that, i.e. we will know of the problem when we commit.

Comment: About cascading, this solution tries to increment version number of each nested item, but what does it do when such an item is currently not in collection and DB? Will if just persist it again to DB with incremented version number? Then it's the same problem again.

Comment: From db operation point of view everything what is in transaction is treated as atomic, so finding entity by Id in transaction and then merging detached entity in the same transaction is treated as atomic. With optimistic locking you do not need use rebeatable reads to find that entity has been changed in another transaction, your commit will throw OptimisticLockException in such situation, even if entity has been deleted.

Comment: About cascading, nope, my solution does not increment version of nested items if there were no changes to them, it cares about increment version of nesting entity if any changes have been done to nested entities. So, if you wil change nested entity, saving it through the nesting entity will increment version of nested and nesting entity in one atomic operation. About second part of your comment, if item is not in collection and not in DB, then it is completely new item even if it has id and version, so it will be persisted with provided id or generated and most probably with provided version.